# Magento 2 does not load local language settings

Tags: magento2

I am having issues with the local settings for magento 2.2.4. Suddenly my locale settings are not applied anymore. For example I have a store with the dutch language, the langague files are installed, the locale settings are set to dutch and I have done the composer update, setup upgrade, static files, varnish cache clean, normal cache etc etc. But nothing helps. It always stays in english. Very annoying. Anybody?

and when I deploy my static files he only deploys en_US. Don't think that's correct

Comment: Try deploying Static Files via CLI, using multiple language flags that you need in the same command. e.g. bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --language en_US --language es_ES [Ref: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html]

Comment: Thanks. he only does en_ US when I try it with ---language or -l but with just  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -s standard nl_NL en_GB de_DE he shows that he does the deploy but doesn't help in the frontend